# Irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to solve the following problem from few days, but yet not get any solution. $$\text{Let $f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$ be irreducible.}$$$$\text{ Then there is no $\alpha\in \Bbb C$ with $f(\alpha)=f(\alpha+1)=0$. }$$

I have tried using the fact that every polynomial over $\Bbb R$ can be written as product of quadratic and linear polynomial. But I don't know what I have to after that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: The polynomial $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$ has $\alpha$ as a root.

Comment: I can't find solution from that. Can you say something more.

Comment: @Mathlover What's the degree of $g$? Now use the fact that $f$ and $g$ have a common root to show that $f$ is reducible.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Degree of $g$ is at most $\text{deg}(f)-1$ and $f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$ is irreducible, so that we have $p(x),q(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that $f(x)p(x)+g(x)q(x)=1$, which contradicts that $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: @Mathlover I was going to say that $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha) = 0$ means that $\gcd(f, g)$ is non-constant but has strictly lower degree than $f$, and therefore $f$ cannot be irreducible. But yes, that way also works just fine. It doesn't matter much at what point in that chain of logic you realize a contradiction.